# Calling an action on ModelAsController subclass

Tags: php, controller, routes, silverstripe

I have a custom route in my `routes.yml` that forwards any unknown request to `BaseController`

```
'$URLSegment/$Name/$Action/$ID': 'BaseController'
```

And from there the the request is routed (among other places) to my main Controller where it is handled by the `index()` of the controller.

However it will always use the `index()` so if I go to the URL `test1/test2/action/5` it will still be run by `index()`

This is my `BaseController`

```
class BaseController extends ModelAsController {
    public function getNestedController() {
        $action 
        $params = $this->getRequest()->params();
        $this->loadMain($params['URLSegment'], $params['Name'], $params['Action'], $params['ID']);
    }
    private function loadMain($first, $name, $action, $id) {
        $main = new MainController();
        $main->{$action}();
    }
}
```

and this will call the function however the `index()` function has already run and set the template.

I know I could call the function from `index()` and return the template like that however I'm fairly sure this would bypass the security features of the allowed actions which I'm keen to maintain.

I've defined `$allowed_actions` in my `MainController` and have added:

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    '$URLSegment/$Name/something/$ID' => 'something'
);
```

but it still just calls `index()`.

How can I maintain the same action routing of SilverStripe through the custom routed `MainController`

Comment: did you flush to get changes in config working?

Comment: @wmk Yes I did.

Comment: You're calling a method by `$main->foo()` (for example). By doing so you will always call `foo`, the `url_handlers` won't change this. I don't really see the point in using the `BaseController`, why don't you just use the `MainController` in the route?

Comment: @FatalError There are things that I do before that that pull additional details from the db to display in the main controller. It's just not important to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't well documented but if you are wanting to reverse the URL convention of /path/$Action/$Name/$ID to something like /path/$Name/$Action then you put:

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'path//$Name/$Action' => 'handleAction'
);
```

The `handleAction is important as it calls the parents (`Controller`) handleAction and routes it correctly applying permissions and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `private static $allowed_actions` and maybe `private static $url_handlers` also, the latter providing custom routing.

Basically all the things from: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/controllers/routing/

Comment: I already had allowed_actions and added url_handlers but that hasn't changed anything. I've updated my questions with more detail.